# YUICompressor error: RuntimeException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: php, symfony, yui-compressor, assetic

I am trying to use YUICompressor with assetic on Symfony 2.0.10 on my dev server (windows 7), and I get this error:

`RuntimeException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

What is the problem?

My current configuration is as follows:

```
filters:
    yui_js:
        jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar"
```

in app/config.yml under assetic.

```
{% javascripts
    '@TonyNachalotoBundle/Resources/public/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js'
    '@TonyNachalotoBundle/Resources/public/js/*.js'
    filter='yui_js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

in my twig template.

Nothing else is set, nothing else is modified, I've been following this article: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

YUICompressor version is 2.4.7

P.S.: Assetic works just fine without the filter, and I've also tried `java -jar yuicompressor.jar ./script.js -o ./test.js` successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the jar is in the correct path? and the correct name?
I had this problem a few weeks ago and I resolved, my YUI Compressor file had different name.

%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore, I'm using Dean Edwards' packer - http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ it's far better than YUI in my case.